# Cross updating several Excel workbook while keeping one master file opened at all times

Tags: vba, excel, real-time

The idea of the Excel is a little complicated. Please bear with me. 
So I have a number of Excel workbooks.

1. Master File
2. Manager A
3. Manager B
4. Manager C

and so on. So the first part of the Excel macro works with a button in each file:

1. I update the Masterfile from columns A:F and push the information
   the respective Manager workbooks based on their names.
2. Managers will update columns G:Z and push the information back to the Master File based on bil number (basically a vlookup vba
   function)

The above excel VBA is done but here comes the issue. Because of Excel limitation, only one person can access a file and update at once. Even with existing files, I can only run the macro when I close the Master File. I am looking for a solution that allows me to have the Master File open permanently (to allow push of information from column A:F to Manager's file) and to pull the information from Manager's file column G:Z simultaneously without closing the Master file. Any recommendations?

With that, I summarize it in 1 in addition to 2 mores requirements that I'm inquiring:

1. Master sheet shall remain open without interruption from on-going activity at the sub-spreadsheets.
2. Master sheet must be updated upon "opening" and "closing" of file. Immediate update to simulate real-time information.
3. Insertion of formula (i.e. KPI calculation based on input dates, to return result (stretch, within target.)

With that I hope to get feedbacks on if these requirements are possible and I will then publish a more detailed code when it's done. Thank you so much for your comments! :)

Comment: Use Access not excel.

Comment: This is what databases are for.

Comment: At least use an Access DB as your back-end data store: you can query and update that from Excel

Comment: @scott craner  Would it be possible with excel though? My current situation is it's hard to manage the database with Access. Right now they are looking at just an excel interim solution.